# XML Schema entitiy relations

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to create a new XML Schema from an ER-Model.
I have the following Model.

```
[Type1]--(1:M)--->(doSomething)<---(0:N)--[Type2]
```

Attributes:

[Type1]: **ID1**, Text

[Type2]: **ID2**, Text

Now I want to create a XML Schema for that Model. I already have create a Schema but I think that I dont have the right relations (1:M) and (0:N).

Can anyone explain me how to implement the right relations?

This is my current XML Schema.

```
<xs:element name="XMLModel">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MyType1" type="type1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:key name="MyType1_ID">
                    <xs:selector xpath="MyType1"/>
                    <xs:field xpath="ID1"/>
                </xs:key>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="MyType2" type="type2" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:key name="MyType2_ID">
                    <xs:selector xpath="MyType2"/>
                    <xs:field xpath="ID2"/>
                </xs:key>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="DoSomething" type="typeDo" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:keyref name="Ref1" refer="MyType1_ID">
                        <xs:selector xpath="DoSomething"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="child::MyType1"/>
                    </xs:keyref>
                    <xs:keyref name="Ref2" refer="MyType2_ID">
                        <xs:selector xpath="DoSomething"/>
                        <xs:field xpath="child::MyType2"/>
                    </xs:keyref>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="type1">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Text" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="ID1" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="type2">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Text" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:element name="ID2" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="typeDo">
<xs:all>
    <xs:element name="MyType1" type="xs:integer"/>
    <xs:element name="MyType2" type="xs:integer"/>
</xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entity model is a many-to-many relationship but an XML document is essentially a hierarchy. You can model one of the one-to-many relationships using the XML hierarchy and the other using primary keys/foreign keys, or you can model both relationships using primary and foreign keys - which is what you are apparently trying to do.

What you have done wrong is to define the keys and keyrefs at the wrong level: they all need to be at the container level (XMLModel). If you want to say that every R in T has a unique value for F, then the key needs to be defined at the level of R, the selector should select R from T, and the field should select F from R.